# How do I connect to an Oracle DB or an Inormix DB through Database Explorer/Server Explorer in visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, server-explorer

I am new so please go easy!

I am using visual studio 2010 express. I use the wizard to add a dataset and my only options are:

- Microsoft Access DB file
- Microsoft SQL server compact
- Microsoft SQL server db file

I have a few different types of databases set up on my system that I typically query from:

- informix odbc
- oracle
- postgre

I am at a loss as to how to get visual studio to recognize these data source types... any help is greatly appreciated